# Минимальное число автобусов в которое вмещается 20 человек

Tags: python

В летний лагерь Нужно отвести n детей и m вожатых с помощью автобусов. Вместимость одного автобуса 20 человек. Нужно вычислить минимальное количество автобусов, необходимое для перевозки людей. Результат в виде целого числа.

Записать так что бы значение n и m можно было менять.

Пробовал через input для каждой переменной, но дальше не получалось определить число автобусов.

```
n = int(input())
m = int(input())
    
#b колл-во автобусов
```

Дальше не знаю что делать

Comment: А как ты ты вручную решал?

Answer (score 3):

Можно решить задачу с помощью простого вычисления и использования функции math.ceil() для округления до ближайшего большего целого числа.

```
import math

# количество детей и вожатых
n = 50
m = 3

# вычисляем общее количество людей
total_people = n + m

# вычисляем необходимое количество автобусов
buses_needed = math.ceil(total_people / 20)

# выводим результат
print(f"Необходимое количество автобусов: {buses_needed}")
```

Comment: `math.ceil(total_people / 20)` -> `(total_people + 20 - 1) // 20`. Не нужно использовать вещественную арифметику в задаче где можно обойтись без неё.